# Sphinx Search indexing some fields but not others

Tags: php, python, mysql, sphinx

I'm using generic Sphinx with Python (though I tested this against PHP as well and got the same problem). I have a table where I have several fields I want to be able to search in sphinx against but it seems like only some of the fields get indexed.

Here's my source (dbconfig just has the connection information):

```
source bill_src : dbconfig
{
    sql_query       = \ 
        SELECT id,title,official_title,summary,state,chamber,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS bill_date FROM bill

    sql_attr_timestamp = bill_date

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM bill WHERE id=$id
}
```

Here's the index

```
index bills
{
    source          = bill_src
    path            = /var/data/bills
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type        = sbcs
}
```

I'm trying to use extended match mode. It seems that `title` and `summary` are fine but the `official_title`, the `state` and the `chamber` fields are ignored in the index. So for example if I do:

`@official_title Affordable Care Act`

I get:

```
query error: no field 'official_title' found in schema
```

but the same query with @summary produces results. Any ideas what I'm missing?

**EDIT**
Here's the table I'm trying to index:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bt50_id            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type               | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| official_title     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| summary            | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| congresscritter_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_action        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sunlight_id        | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| number             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state              | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chamber            | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session            | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| featured           | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| source_url         | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: If elected president I will make sure that the same query produces results

Comment: This sounds like you havent correctly restarted search daemon. It's probably best to shutdown searchd, rebuild the index, and start up the daemon again. Its easy to get wires crossed during development as playing with the settings.

Comment: @barryhunter Unfortunately I tried that. I went so far as to actually delete the indexes on disk and recreate them. I still receive the same issue.

Comment: Try using indextool to inspect your index.  (also was searchd shutdown, when you deleted the files? If not, it would still have them open. Linux only actully deletes files when nothing is using them)

Comment: Also are you using SphinxQL to query your index? If so try a "describe bills" in sphinx. If using sphinxAPI do a print_r() on the result of Query on a query that does work, and check the Fields array.

Comment: @barryhunter - definitely shut it down and deleted the indexes. I also use --rotate with sends a SIGHUP every time.  I seem to have fixed it though. It appears that the attribute stuff has to go last and a timestamp has to be named the same as the field name ... so my `AS bill_date changed` to `AS last_action`. (I had changed that previously but moved that attribute to the front originally but still had the problem).

Comment: @Cfreak: if you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it, for future googlers' sake.

Comment: @thg435 not sure if it will help but I posted my own answer

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed the problem, though I'll admit this is all dumb luck so it might not be a root cause:

First I thought maybe it didn't like the order of the fields in the query I have the only attribute field last so I decided to move it to after the ID:

```
 SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS bill_date, \
     title,official_title,summary,state,chamber, FROM bill
```

This did not fix the problem.

Secondly, I noticed all the example date fields are converted using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and then aliased to the same name, so instead of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS bill_date` I changed it to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS last_action` ... the first attempt tripped me up though because it still wasn't working.

Finally I dropped the date altogether and added each field successfully (re-indexing and testing each time). Each time it worked and finally I added the date field on the end and I was able to sort by it and search all the fields. So the final query is:

```
    SELECT \
      id,title,official_title,summary,state,chamber, \ 
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS last_action FROM bill
```

It seems that attribute fields must come after the full text fields and aliases must be the same name as the actual field name. I find it strange that the date field seemed fine but other fields suddenly disappeared (randomly!).

I hope this helps someone else though I feel it might be some kind of isolated bug that doesn't affect many people. (This is on OSX and sphinx was compiled by hand)

Comment: Which version are you using ? I tried 2.0.6 & trunk under linux and I can't replicate your bug.

Comment: Hmm, I still say something else was going on. The order of the columns within the dataset make no difference (other than the id must always be first). And sphinx has no way of knowing if the column is using the same alias as the column name. Here is a complex example config http://svn.geograph.org.uk/svn/branches/british-isles/system/sphinxserver/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf - that does not follow any of your conventions, yet works just fine.

Comment: Also note that your first example query (with bill_date at the beginning) is missing a comma after, so would not work anyway. Probably you where failing to reindex at all.

Comment: @barryhunter definitely indexing. the comma was just an oversight when I was trying to format it for SO

Comment: @barryhunter - I agree. I just posted this as steps that solved the problem for me. According to the docs the original config should have been fine.

Comment: @aditirex - 2.0.6 on Mac OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Little rusty on sphinx, but believe in your `source { }` clause needs a **sql_field_string** definition.

```
source bill_src : dbconfig
{
    sql_query       = \ 
        SELECT \
          id,title,official_title,summary,state,chamber, \
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_action) AS bill_date \
        FROM bill

    sql_attr_timestamp = bill_date
    sql_field_string = official_title

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM bill WHERE id=$id
}
```

According to http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-sql-field-string.html the sql_field_string declaration will index and store the string for referencing. That's different from a sql_attr_string, which is stored but not indexed.

Comment: Also, that doc is a random google result. Should check against your sphinx version.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. `sql_field_string` just means it can be used as an attribute and a full-text field. I'm only trying to use it as a full-text field. (for fun I did try it but got the same result)

Comment: Can you revise the question to add a dump of "describe bill" ?

Comment: Exactly, sql_field_string  only need to used if want the column to become both a field and an attribute. A column not defined as an attribute, is automatically a field.

Comment: Have you attempted to prefix the query with @@relaxed ? Does it spit out actual data with that?